# How to get internet connection through USB-tethering / hotspot to work for other applications than browsers?

Tags: windows-10, android, hotspot

When connected through my phone (using USB thethering or wifi hotspot) my internet generally works fine: I have no issues using my browser. However, other applications (IntelliJ, Spotify) throw me connection issues, what seems to be connection time-outs.
This however is not always the case and hasn't always been the case; it's only since this week I have these issues. When I connect to a normal wifi network I have no issues.

What could this be related to? Is there a firewall in my phone (Android) blocking connections through certain ports? Is it my provider blocking things?

**Edit**: USB-tethering with my phone connected to a wifi network causes no problems.

Comment: What ports are those programs using to connect to the internet? It is possible that your mobile provider has blocked those ports, for example several providers in the UK block Steam and BitTorrent ports on their networks.

Comment: @Burgi OK, thanks, that could b the case. But wouldn't it be weird that sometimes it does work and other times not?

Comment: It is possible they are also throttling you, maybe a quick call to their customer service team might shed some more light on the issue.

Comment: Thanks! I'll contact them. I'll keep this question updated

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a proxy? Maybe your phone and computer are setup to use proxy and other applications are not.

If so, try settings applications to use system proxy settings or set it manually.